# Why are eigenvariables called eigenvariables?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

I was learning about the Sequent Calculus in class earlier today, and was wondering why eigenvariables are given that name.  Is there any relation or analogy between the roots of characteristic polynomials and eigenvariables?

Comment: I dont know but eigen- comes from german and translates as "charasteristic" so using it outside the context of linear algebra is fine

Comment: What name would you prefer?

Answer (score 3):

Sequent calculus was invented by the German logician [Gerhard Gentzen (1909 – 1945)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Gentzen).

The English translation of his [The collected papers (1969)](https://books.google.it/books?id=81ELAQAAIAAJ), page 77, does not translate the German term : *eigenvariable* [ "*proper* variable" would work ?]

The first influential textbooks dedicated to sequent calculus use the untranslated "eigenvariable" :

- [Kurt Schütte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Sch%C3%BCtte), [Proof theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=3sbqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20) (1977, 1st German ed., 1960) : German mathematician;
- [Gaisi Takeuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaisi_Takeuti), [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&pg=PA10) (1st ed, 1975) : Japanese mathematician, that studied at Princeton with Kurt Gödel.

Thus, the German influence prevailed and the tradition has been settled.

Comment: +1 To clarify for the OP:  the analogy is just the untranslated "eigen", not anything to do with eigenvalues as the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @EthanBolker - please, note that "variable" in German is *variable*.